# Data output in real time to the browser without restarting node js, websocket?

Tags: html, node.js, websocket

I need to get currency quotes in real time, without reloading the page and clicking on buttons.

To solve this problem, we had to resort to the following technologies: node js, websocket.io, Redis, data donor API.

In the console I get the following data:

```
{"symbol": "EURUSD", "bid": 1.13624, "ask": 1.13624, "price": 1.13624}
```

in fact, everything works, and this is what I need. But, I can not figure out how to transfer the same data to the browser, so that it would be like this:

```
EURUSD | bid - 1.13624 | ask - 1.13624 | price - 1.13624
```

Here is the js code:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const settings = {
    REDIS: {
        HOST: 'localhost'
    }
}
let redisClient = new redis.createClient(settings.REDIS);

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

function getQuote(symbol, callback) {
    redisClient.get(symbol, (error, quote) => {
        if (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
        quote = JSON.parse(quote);
        callback(quote);
    });
}

setInterval(() => {
    getQuote('EURUSD', (q) => {
        const formattedQ = `${q.SYMBOL} | bid - ${q.bid} | ask - ${q.ask} | price - ${q.price}`;
        console.log(formattedQ);
    });
}, 10);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('get_quote', function(msg){
        io.emit('get_quote', getQuote('EURUSD', (q) => /* ??? what to insert here? -> (formattedQ) ??? */));
    });
});
```

And HTML file:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('get_quote', function(msg){
      // ??? what to insert here to update quotes without rebooting ???
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a more suitable approach would be to send the json as-is, and format it in the client.

```js
/* redis connection code */
setInterval(() => {
    getQuote('EURUSD', (q) => {
        const formattedQ = `${q.SYMBOL} | bid - ${q.bid} | ask - ${q.ask} | price - ${q.price}`;
        console.log(formattedQ);
    });
}, 10);
```

## Update

I'm revising the answer because I think it would be easier to show a piece of code I believe would work. 
In order to send data from the server to the client, you should use the `io.emit()` function, which you do - but you wrapped it in a `socket.on('get_quote')`. Basically what will happen is that you will emit a new message only if a message was received (resulting in a deadlock).

I believe this snippet should work:

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    setInterval(() => {
        getQuote('EURUSD', (q) => {
            io.emit('get_quote', q);
        });
    }, 10);
});
```

This would initialize an interval when there is a connection to the server, and emit a new `q` every 10 seconds.
Then, in your HTML file you should receive the q (in JSON form), and format it the way you choose:

```js
socket.on('get_quote', function(msg){
    console.log(`${msg.SYMBOL} | bid - ${msg.bid} | ask - ${msg.ask} | price - ${msg.price}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Something is wrong:
1. I get undefined
undefined | bid - undefined | ask - undefined | price - undefined

2. I would like to clarify. My problem is that I don’t know how to output data to the browser (html page), I have already learned to the console :)

I changed my question, added code, maybe there is too much or something is missing for proper operation.

Comment: Do you receive a properly formatted `msg` in the HTML file?

Comment: Not. I do not understand how to pass data from the getQuote function to html. I thought that this can be done using emit, but I don’t know how to write it correctly. Maybe I’m moving the wrong way ...

Comment: I've revised the answer, I hope it solves your problem

Comment: Thank you, Dor Shinar! With your help everything turned out. The prices are a little suspiciously updated, it may just be too late, and the market is closed. I will know tomorrow.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! Please mark my answer as the correct answer so other people will benefit as well.

Comment: It is not very important, but I ask, do not tell me how to apply to several currencies at once? For example: getQuote('EURUSD, BTCUSD', (q) => { io.emit('get_quote', q); }); Can you directly contact you directly? :) Sure, I still have questions.

Comment: The purpose of StackOverflow is to allow many people access to the questions and answers. If you have any further questions please post them as questions on the site, and I'll be glad to help there as well.